# Change the look of a RibbonRadioButton

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribbon

I am developing a `Ribbon` for my WPF application and I need to add two `RibbonRadioButton` into a `RibbonGroup`. I already did this, and everything works perfectly:

```
<rb:RibbonGroup>

   <rb:RibbonRadioButton Label="Option one" IsChecked="{Binding OptionOne}"  />
   <rb:RibbonRadioButton Label="Option two" IsChecked="{Binding OptionTwo}" />

</rb:RibbonGroup>
```

But the RibbonRadioButtons look like a **"conventional buttons"** and I need them to look like the **classic pushable RadioButtons** we all know which are made up of a little circle and a label.

So, **Is there a way to change the look of the `RibbonRadioButtons`??**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<rb:RibbonMenuButton.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="RibbonRadioButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type rb:RibbonRadioButton}">
        <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=rb:RibbonGroup}}" Content="{TemplateBinding Label}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</rb:RibbonMenuButton.Resources>

    <rb:Ribbon HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="111,86,0,88.867" Width="289.14">
    <rb:RibbonGroup x:Name="grp1">
         <rb:RibbonRadioButton Label="Option one" IsChecked="{Binding OptionOne}" Template="{DynamicResource RibbonRadioButtonControlTemplate1}"  />
         <rb:RibbonRadioButton Label="Option two" IsChecked="{Binding OptionTwo}" Template="{DynamicResource RibbonRadioButtonControlTemplate1}" />
    </rb:RibbonGroup>
    </rb:Ribbon>
```

Comment: In order to get this to work, I had to change the binding on the `IsChecked` property to the following so that it could find the right source: `{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Ribbon:RibbonRadioButton}}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the template of the standard RadioButton : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751600.aspx

Edit :

I thought RibbonRadioButton was your own control ; but it's new in .net 4.5 ?! I can't find its template on the msdn though, so I guess you'll have to get it by Blend. Drop the control on a new windows of a new Blend WPF project ; right click the control on the design view -> edit template -> edit a copy ; then you can edit the template in the "xaml view"...

Comment: Thanks for answering but that style seems not to work on a `RibbonRadioButton`

Comment: +1 for the Blend direction, if you don't have blend though you can always do a search through your solution in VS for a string like x:Key="RibbonControlStyle" and you should be able to find the default template that way also.

Comment: @ChrisW. I am not able no find such string since the Ribbon controls are in a DLL which was released by Microsoft

Comment: @Dante - Sorry I've been working in SL too long apparently. Then my next route would be the same as what franssu describes in Expression Blend.